# Visual Studio Code / C++ : Intellisense not showing quick info with method documentation (signature help)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I recently installed VSCode for my C++ projects. That's a great tool, very light, easy to use and no trouble to install C++ dedicated extensions. But I've realized after checking some videos/documentation about VSCode, IntelliSense is not fully working in my environment. So far, most IntelliSense features I've used work well...except Quick Info feature to show accompanying documentation for a method (signature help). As I can see from C++ tutorials/videos using VSCode, I should have a Quick Info blue icon when writing a method that expands to the side parameter info.

In my case there is no Quick Info  blue icon, there is just the parameters name or short info. Im figuring out since several days why my VSCode is not able to provide the Signature help feature. I also tried with C#, but I get same behavior...

So Im heading to the StackOverflow community to get help. I've seen so many things about VScode on the Web but nothing concerning my issue.

**My configuration:**

- MacBookPro - MacOS Catalina V10.15.4 (OS: Darwin x64 19.4.0)
- VSCode Version: 1.45.1
- C++ Microsoft (ms-vscode.cpptools) extension
- C++ Intellisense (austin.code-gnu-global) extension

> UserSettings:

```
"editor.detectIndentation": false,
"editor.multiCursorModifier": "alt",
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
"workbench.view.alwaysShowHeaderActions": true,
"C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
"editor.insertSpaces": false,
"editor.minimap.maxColumn": 100,
"editor.minimap.size": "fill",
"editor.tabSize": 4,
"task.saveBeforeRun": "never",
"window.closeWhenEmpty": true,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
"workbench.editor.closeEmptyGroups": false,
"workbench.editor.showTabs": true,
"workbench.settings.editor": "json",
"workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings": true,
"workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": true
```

**Example with pictures:**

[My working Environment without quick info blue icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Bt3.png)

[C++ example with quick info blue icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Nsv.png)
(source : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Tc6f3nhCxo)

Thank you in advance for your help!

**For more details, here are some c++ IntelliSense Settings**

```
> "C_Cpp.autocomplete": "Default",
  "C_Cpp.default.intelliSenseMode": "",
  "C_Cpp.intelliSenseCachePath": "",
  "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Default",
  "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngineFallback": "Disabled"
```

Comment: Have you checked that the intellisense engine is set to default and not tag parser?

Comment: @Ben : Yes, Cpp engine is currently set to "default" -> "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Default"

Comment: I had similar issue, But when I closed all instances of my Visual Studio Code and reopened the visual studio code, methods quick info started working fine in IntelliSense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced the same problem getting VS Code C++ IntelliSense Quick Info to work on Mac M1 (arm64) without having to install Xcode for personal reasons (large and not needed).

Simply using the gcc provided by homebrew did the trick.

Make sure to install [Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666134/how-to-install-homebrew-on-m1-mac) first if not installed

Then install gcc

`brew install gcc`

Open your ***c_cpp_properties.json*** file in ***.vscode*** directory and replace the ***compilerPath*** value with the one from homebrew.

`"compilerPath": "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0/bin/g++-11"`

In my case this is gcc-11 with version 11.2.0. Yours may be different so confirm from the `brew install gcc` output or confirm manually.

(This solution should work for MacOS and isn't limited to just the M1.)

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved my Intellisense issue on my VS code configuration!

Now "Quick Info" feature is shown when I start typing functions, methods or whatever.

It has been fixed after installing xcode macOS application and updating gcc version by Homebrew (see attached pictures).

[gcc version 10.2.0 on Homebrew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGTn6.png)

[my cpp configuration (c_cpp_properties.json)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KgBV.png)

Hope it may help other people that have same Intellisense issue to show accompanying documentation for a method (signature help).

Comment: Good to hear! Please mark your own answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
           "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22000.0",
        "compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

- I've changed my **includePath** and **compilerPath** according to my source of installation. where in my case, it is from MSYS - as referred [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_run-helloworldcpp) by vs_code team.