# Homebrew doesn't stay installed? M1 Macbook

Tags: macos, installation, package, homebrew

I've upgraded to an M1 Macbook Pro and need to reinstall all of the goodies that I use regularly.

This includes Homebrew.

I have been to the official Homebrew site and done what they suggest:

> /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

It then suggests to run

> echo '# Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.' >> /Users/username/.bash_profile
> echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/username/.bash_profile
> eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

To keep it within the path for future use - I would think this was the thing that keeps it being reusable when you restart/get a new Terminal

And this works great. I can then use `brew install xxx` after installation to install whatever packages I require.

The issue comes when I get a new Terminal or restart etc. I go to perform another `brew install` and I get the annoying

> -bash: brew: command not found

Is there something that I've not done after the initial install that means my Mac doesn't remember it's installed brew?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue as you. My issue was my terminal was set to bash instead of zsh by default. I had to run `chsh -s /bin/zsh` and followed the [top answer on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666134/how-to-install-homebrew-on-m1-mac), which is similar if not identical to the steps you include in your question. I restarted my terminal and ran through `brew help` worked!